# Tengo muchas dudas acerca de parseInt, no logro entender nada

Tags: javascript

estoy en un curso para postular a una escuela de Programación pero por más que he buscado, no logro entender el parseInt, alguien podría explicarme?

Comment: podrías empezar por agregar el ejemplo con el que estas trabajando en la clase y de ahi partimos, por que, que exactamente no entiendes? parseInt() parsea un string o un numero con decimales y devuelve su entero

Answer (score 2):

[La documentación de MDN tiene buena información sobre la función `parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt).

Vamos a suponer que tienes una cadena de texto con un número:

```
let numeroA = '10';
```

La variable `numeroA` contiene una cadena de texto `string`, la cual contiene los caracteres `11`. Pero esto no es un número, es una cadena de texto la cual resulta tener caracteres numéricos.

La función `parseInt()` puede tomar este valor y convertirlo a un número.

```
let numeroB = parseInt(numeroA);
```

Lo cual va a almacenar en la variable `numeroB` un tipo de dato numérico.

La función `parseInt()` tiene muchas opciones como convertir números en diferentes bases (decimal, octal, hexadecimal), checar si lo que se introduce no se puede interpretar como un número (para lo cuál la función devolvería un `NAN`).